# VNC Server is accessible only for localhost

Tags: networking, firewall, vnc

I've set up TigerVNC server on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but I can connect to it only from the server.
If I run `nmap localhost -p 5901`, it says that the port is open. But, when I run `nmap 192.168.0.101 -p 5901` where `192.168.0.101` is LAN IP of my server, it says that the port is closed. After I read some questions similar to this one, "closed" port means there is no service listening to it. But the VNC Server is running...

I'm trying to solve this for a few days, but still nothing. Here is my previous question: [VNC Server port is closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253599/vnc-server-port-is-closed)

I've already tried to allow port 5901 in ufw. I even created a custom ufw application in ufw, but the port is still closed for other computers in the LAN. Only localhost sees it as open. Could something block the VNC Server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TigerVNC by default listens only on the *loopback* network interface.
This is good for security, so that only you on the very same computer can connect.

Of course, if you want to connect remotely, you need to specifically specify it as follows:

1. When you start the server from the command line, add `-localhost no` to the command line.

   ```
   tigervncserver -localhost no :1
   ```
2. Configure TigerVNC to permanently listen to all network interfaces in `/etc/vnc.conf`. Add the following. Note that the configuration file gives the impression that `no` is the default. They do not follow the convention that if a configuration is commented out in the config file, it should have the default value (and not the other value you would normally change to).

   ```
   $localhost = "no";
   ```

Comment: Thank you!! I thought there was something wrong with firewall. Thank you so much, I spent so many hours to fix this.

Comment: Could you please edit this answer? There must be a semicolon after that line, otherwise, vncserver will output some errors with semicolons. E. g. $localhost = "no";

Comment: it's "good for security" when remote desktop software defaults to being unable to do what it's designed to do?